# convert pandas time column to datetime column

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have read-only access to data where time is stored as *time* object (date is irrelevant). I need to subtract a few seconds from each row. So the simplest way I know is to use *timedelta*, but first, I need to convert *time* column to *datetime* column. There should be a straight-forward way to do that; apparently there is not.

Comment: Probably easier to convert `time` col to a `pd.TimeDelta` with `pd.to_timedelta()`.

Comment: ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I found a solution that was obscured by many wired workarounds. It required format argument: pd.to_datetime(measures.time,format='%H:%M:%S'), where format must be exactly the same as time is formatted.

A one-line solution if anybody will come with similar question:

time = (pd.to_datetime(measures.time,format='%H:%M:%S') - delta).dt.time
where measures is a dataset and time is column name